# how to make parent div adapt size of child

Tags: html, css, height

I try to have a div around a fixed-size canvas and the div should adapt the same size in a tight fit.

For the width, I use `width:fit-content`.

However, I cannot make the height fit. The parent is always some pixels larger.

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6jabuwh2/2/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to the parent.

For more information about flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Change `display: inine-block` to `display:block;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/szLv6hua/